# Vlookup without repetition using vba on excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, match, vlookup

I am trying to put in place a macro that allows me to match identical entry from one table to another. The tricky part is that if a match is found, it cannot be repeated. The way I theorized it is kind of elementary, however it is the only way I can think of it given my still limited knowledge in VBA.

**The structure**

1. Both tables need to be first filtered in order to allow the non-repetition condition.
2. Store the searching values as arrays in order to speed up the process of the macro
3. Match the entries to search with the ones from the targeted table in order to find matches. This is done with the in-application function MATCH. The MATCH function returns the cell where the match is situated, this is useful as it constantly shift the range in order to not repeate the same value all the time.
4. After calculating the shifting range, I use a VLookup function in order to return the second entry.

Unfortunately, the macro is incomplete. I cannot find a way to constantly shift the range without compromising the mechanism. The problem resides in the shifting range that is not created correctly to shift after each match.

**Desired result**

In the below image the desired result would be to check if all items in the left table are in the right table. Take item A, I need to find two item As. I have in the right column a first item A with value 17 and a second item A with value 81. If I do not find any value I have nothing, as it is the case of Ds and E. If instead I have less entries in the left table (as it is for the case of entry L) then I need to return all values of Entry L: 96; 77; 40.

[image]

```
    Sub Matching11()
ThisWorkbook.Activate

Worksheets.add

Worksheets("Test4").Range("A1:T110").copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

With ActiveSheet

    Dim Search_Array As Variant
    Search_Array = Range("C2", Range("C1").End(xlDown)) 'use this array to loop through the value to search for


    Dim Target_MatchValue As Integer
    Dim Target_Range As Range
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim n As Integer



    counter = 0
    n = 0
    Target_MatchValue = 0

    For counter = LBound(Search_Array) To UBound(Search_Array)
        Target_MatchValue = 0

        Target_MatchValue = Application.Match(Search_Array(counter, 1), .Range("H2:H200"), 0) - 1 'change C column with the range where you will have the tyres you need search for
        Set Target_Range = .Range(.Cells(2 + n, 8), .Cells(1000, 9))  'this is supposed to work as a shifting range allowing to match entries without making repetitions. I used the MATCH function in order to set the start of the range. i.e. if there is a match in the target table the range will shift from the location of the match downwards. If the match is at on the same level then it does not shift the range in order to match the same-level entry afterwards it is supposed to shift by one unit in order to prevent repetitions.
        'If arr = Application.VLookup(Search_Array(counter, 1), Target_Range, 2, False) Is Nothing Then GoTo NextCounter    'I used Vlookup in order to return the value set in the second column of the targetted table. As alternative, I think I could just use offset since I previously used MQTCH


        arr = Application.VLookup(Search_Array(counter, 1), Target_Range, 2, False)
        If IsError(arr) Then
            GoTo NextCounter
            Else
            .Range(Cells(1 + counter, 6), Cells(1 + counter, 6)).value = arr 'Return the value of the array in this cell
        End If
        Target_Range.Select

        If Target_MatchValue = 0 Then

            n = n + 1

            ElseIf Target_MatchValue > 0 Then
            n = n + Target_MatchValue
        End If
        .Range(Cells(1 + counter, 5), Cells(1 + counter, 5)).value = Search_Array(counter, 1) 'Return the value of the array in this cell
    Next counter

NextCounter:
Next counter

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I did not understand very well what you mean. You may be interested in VLOOKUP() and HLOOKUP() functions.

Comment: Vlookup returns always the same value

Comment: Read the help for vlookup() carefully. The data must be sorted, or the third parameter must be set accordingly. The column with the keys should not have duplicate values. Otherwise, the result is not what you want. Noo algorithm can decide which value you want, if you have two values associated with the same key (A -> Row1, A -> Row2). How can the algorithm decide how to choose between Row1 and Row2?

Comment: The point is that I have duplicates in the second table, and they are meant to be there for specific reasons. I need to match entries from table 1 to entries in table 2. In other words I need to link the entries in table 1 to all entries in table 2 without repeating them. I have theorized it given the above code, I am aware there might be other more elegant ways but this is the max I can do. I am planning to do it by shifting the range of the Vlookup by one unit downward every time it finds something so that matches do not repeat.

Comment: Then maybe you should use c1=h1, d1=i1, c2=h2, d2=i2... and so on... You just duplicate the data with the most basic formula.

Comment: I can't see how it can be automatized to thousands of entries though

Comment: Your specification is very weak. Example: why did you added 2 lines with "D" in column C? Even crazier: 2 lines with "i", one has Row10, the other is blank... You need to be able to describe in words all rules and all exceptions, and then the algorithm will be easier to find.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. In your image there are 2 tables: would left table be your input and right table your expected output? Because right table looks like you filtered and/or hided those rows where field "Result" is blank in left table

Comment: Yes, the input are values in the left table. Maybe you can help me in clarify. So what I need to do is to find whether the entries in the left table are in the right table. In case they are in the right table, I would need to get the value from the adjacent cell. @virolino This is an example of a list I can have. If Item A is in the right table I need to get the value that is linked to item A in the right table. If I have two item A in the left table I need to find the first value of item A and the second item of Item A. Hope this helps

Comment: You can try the following: for each line in the C:D range you parse the entire H:I range, until you find a match. If you find a match, you do what you need to do. If you do not find a match, you will probably do nothing. You need 2 nested "for" loops, of course.

Comment: Another option would be to calculate some helper columns, simply joining the values. Then hopefully you will have unique values and you can use VLOOKUP() with the calculated values. E.g.: E1=C1&D1, J1=H1&I1, E2=C2&D2, J2=H2&I2, ...

Comment: Loops must be very limited as my database have many entries (approx 7000) and their running time would be immense and worthless.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Let's see if this helps you out and probably you can adapt it to your needs.

I replied your data like this:

[image]

The macro will create a list in columns H:I like the right table of your image. The macro will always delete any previous result. My macro works on *standard* ranges, is not designed to work on tables (ListObjects in VBA), but you can easily adapt it to your needs.

```
Sub CREATE_LIST()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long


'we clear previous list
Columns("H:I").Delete

'we add data
Range("H1").Value = "Target"
Range("I1").Value = "Return"

LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Last row of column C, where data is.

Set MyRange = Range("D2:D" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23) 'we select only NON BLANK cells

i = 2 'initial row

For Each rng In MyRange
    Range("H" & i).Value = rng.Offset(0, -1).Value 'value of adjacent cell (Column C)
    Range("I" & i).Value = rng.Value 'value of cell in column D
    i = i + 1
Next rng

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

After executing code I get:
[image]

And trying different data works too:
[image]

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: I have updated the code but it still does not work as it supposed to. Please take a look.

Comment: The code needs to verify if the entries in left table are in right table. The code now verifies them but whereas the first set of  entries are verified without repetition of the return values when the code encounters following entries it just verify the first one and skip to retry the following entries

Comment: @Alessio_110 What do you mean with *when the code encounters following entries it just verify the first one and skip*??

Comment: I was looking for a macro that could would behave as vlookup without repeating the same value over and over

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the unclear explanation of the problem. I have provided here below a solution I have sorted out. I was looking for a code that could execute vlookup without returning the same values. Below is the solution. I am aware that the code might not be the cleanest and most elegant one but it is effective and run fast enough for large data sample.

```
Sub Matching()

    Dim Search_Array As Variant
    Dim Target_MatchValue As Variant
    Dim Target_Range As Range
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    'data must be ordered in order to apply the non-repetitive condition
    Search_Array = Sheet1.Range("A2", Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)) 'use this array to loop through the value to search for


    n = 0
    Sheet1.Activate
    With ActiveSheet
        For counter = LBound(Search_Array) To UBound(Search_Array)

            Target_MatchValue = 0
            Target_MatchValue = Application.Match(Search_Array(counter, 1), .Range(Cells(2 + n, 4), Cells(1000, 4)), 0) 'This code will return the value used for the shifting range
            Set Target_Range = .Range(Cells(2 + n, 4), Cells(1000, 5))  'this is supposed to work as a shifting range allowing to match entries without making repetitions. I used the MATCH function in order to set the start of the range. i.e. if there is a match in the target table the range will shift from the location of the match downwards. If the match is at on the same level then it does not shift the range in order to match the same-level entry afterwards it is supposed to shift by one unit in order to prevent repetitions.
            'target_range.select Activate this code in order to see the macro in action
            arr = Application.VLookup(Search_Array(counter, 1), Target_Range, 2, False) 'store the vlookup value in an array in order to increase the efficiency the code and to speed up the whole proces

                If IsError(arr) Then
                    .Cells(2 + n, 2).value = "" 'if the macro does not find anything, no value will be recorded anywhere

                    Else
                    .Cells(1 + n + Target_MatchValue, 2).value = Search_Array(counter, 2)  'Return the value of the search_array in this cell so to match column A values with column D values if they are found

                End If

                If IsError(arr) Then
                        n = n
                    ElseIf Target_MatchValue = 0 Then 'if the macro does not find anything, the shifting range does not shift so that subsequent values can be searched in the same range without missing precious matches
                        n = n + 1

                    ElseIf Target_MatchValue > 0 Then 'if there is a matching value between Column A and Column B, the shifting range shifts by the n + the distance between the the current vlookupvalue and the found value. Note that Data must be stored in a filtered order otherwise vlookup will not work correctly
                        n = n + Target_MatchValue

                End If
        Next counter

    End With

End Sub
```

By exchanging ideas with some friends, I was told to think about a potential helper column that would be used to store incremental numbers. This helper column would store incremental numbers that would help to meet the non-repetition condition. Please see the below example.

[image]

The idea here is that if a value is found in column E, I store n being equal to the value found in the helper column. Then the code needs to verify if the future values' n are bigger than previous n. If this condition is met, then the one-repetition condition is fulfilled. n changes value to the next bigger value. 
For example, if I find L in the right table, I report 96 as value and store N being equal to 11. When I search for the next value of L, the new n must be bigger than the current n otherwise I will not store the new found value. The value 77 found has indeed a bigger n than the previous value as 12 is bigger than 11. I hope this helps.

Comment: Your original question and this has absolutey nothing in common, LoL. In your first question you ignored blank values, and now you just are kind of moving values one or 2 rows higher. Why now B appears in the results with 56 when 56 is related to C? Why D dissapears when it has a 99?. Totally different question. Anyways, if you found a solution for your problem, that's all that matters, so good job.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I did not know how to put it into words I suppose. I just wanted to find a macro that would vlookup values without returning the same value over and over